# What is the icon?

Tags: discussion

I've discovered this section of Stack Exchange and I like it.  However, the icon here is confusing me.

[image: Icon]

What is this?  Perhaps a Japanese character?  If so what does it mean?  Is it open to change?

I have seen other beta sites that have the blue background with something special (like the [Lego](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/) one)

[image: Lego]

Also, there are multiple icons that are just the blue background with a couple letters from the page title, like [Board Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/)

[image: Board Games]

Comment: For the meaning, check out [this post](https://www.facebook.com/AnimeAndMangaQA/posts/556218247744619) from our facebook page. There we explain the meaning of that kanji, which is used in our community logo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The icon is the kanji 画, which can mean either brush-stroke or picture (the latter seems to be the meaning intended here). It has many different pronunciations (my dictionary lists 9) so I won't list them all here. It is used in a number of art-related Japanese words, including the words for picture (画像), artist (画家), and to draw (画する). Perhaps most relevant for this site, it's also used in *manga* (漫画).

Comment: I can't speak for Jin (the Great Bacon-eating SE Design Overload), but I assume that since 動画 and 漫画 shared a character that it was used.

Comment: @Krazer That's plausible. As a note to anyone who doesn't know Japanese, 動画 is the Japanese word for animation (though *anime* is written in katakana as アニメ, being the shortened form of the word "animation" borrowed in Japanese, and doesn't include 画).

Answer (score 2):

This is the temporary icon given to us (this site, http://anime.stackexchange.com) by Stack Exchange.

It will (maybe) change when we graduate, and we can try to ask for it to be changed, if you propose an alternative, and it gets voted positively here on meta.

Comment: But what is the current one?  I've seen many similar icons that just have letters but this one id unique.  I'll add some more to the question.